# Avoid scientific notation in custom grid labels in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

In previous versions of QGIS I used this expression to make 3-figure coordinates for my maps:

`substr(  @grid_number , length(  @grid_number ) -4,3)`

At the 4000000 mark this used to give me a value of 000.

In this version of QGIS the value I get is 4e+. 
All the other coordinates are correct.

Anybody knows why this happens or how I can remedy this?

Comment: What do u want to achieve ? Don't u want to have the 3 leftmost digit of the number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by altering my original expression very slightly.

Since I was getting a single instance where the figure returned was not numerical I added an `IF` protocol which dealt with that specific value. The expression now reads:

```
if( @grid_number ='4000000','000', substr(  @grid_number , length(  @grid_number ) -4,3))
```

Not very elegant but it worked!

Comment: Don't forget to accept a solution for your answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side to mark this problem as solved :)

Answer (score 3):

Keith is talking about an issue, that me and other people are having on QGIS3, see next link:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15880
It seems still not fixed.
My solution is convert (using refactor field or field calculator), all numeric fields with 7 or more digits, from integer to double.
Hope this help.

Comment: the problem with this is that i'm not working with fields. my problem appears directly on the grid

Comment: Follow up : https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18302 : "On some places it has been fixed, on many it hasn't."

Answer (score 3):

Maybe late to the party, but it might help somebody who is experiencing the same and wants to solve it more dynamically.

For me the following helped:

```
to_string(to_int(@grid_number))
```

Also not very elegant, but might be more useful than checking against a specific value. In my case I used it in a composer template for the frame coordinates where I don't know beforehand what the northing is.

Comment: The root of the solution (whether its grid numbers you're needing to convetr back to 'normal notation', or in my case, the map scale), **to_int()** is a part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what u really want to achieve but i'm pretty u have to play with a type conversion...

Did you try something like `to_string(@grid_number)` in your formula?

Comment: Working on some maps and the clients insisted on 3-digit grid references. is it possible to convert grid values into strings?

Answer (score 1):

For the Attribute Table issues, I avoided scientific notation by just using the **.txt format** instead of csv. when importing data into QGIS, even though the data sample does not show it.